# How to install matplotlib on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started using python and definitely need the matplotlib. I'm confused by the fact that there is even not a clear explanation for the basic ideas behind install a lib/package in python generally. Anyway, I'm using windows and have installed Python 3.4.2 downloaded from the offical website, how should I install the matplotlib?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). It contains lots of easy to install binaries packages for windows. Including matplotlib.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/users/installing.html#windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the matplotlib site above will do the job!
The same procedure you will have to follow to install numpy, which I guess you will also need.